# Segmentation fault in Assembly and string

Tags: linux, assembly

I am trying to make a simple program in assembler, but I do not understand why, I get a fault.
I' ve a 64 bit machine running Ubuntu 12.04, and "as" as a assembly compiler.
My goal merely is to print the string "Hello" on screen.

I wrote this:

```
#print.s
.section .data
.globl StringToPrint

 StringToPrint: .asciz "Hello"

 .globl _start

  _start:       
    movq $4, %rax
    movq $1, %rbx
    movq $StringToPrint, %rcx
    movq $5, %rdx
    int $0x80
 _done:    
    ret
```

But that's what I get:

```
$ as print.s -o print.o
$ ld print.o -o print
$ ./print
Hello[1]    10679 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./print
```

Why do you think this happens? Any idea?

Comment: Use gdb to step through your code and debug the problem.

Comment: Since you're writing 64-bit code, consider switching to using the `syscall` instruction instead of `int $0x80`.

Comment: What happens if you change `.section .data` to `.section .text`?

Comment: I changed the section but it is still the same, moreover I discovered that at the end of the program, due to the ret statement, the value 0x0..1 is poped into rip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix :

```
#print.s
.section .data

.globl StringToPrint
    StringToPrint: .asciz "Hello"   

.globl _start

  _start:

        movl    $5, %edx             # string length
        movl    $StringToPrint, %ecx # pointer to string to write
        movl    $1, %ebx             # file handle (stdout)
        movl    $4, %eax             # system call number (sys_write)
        int     $0x80                # Passes control to interrupt vector

        #sys_exit (return_code)  
        movl    $1, %eax             #System call number 1: exit()
        movl    $0, %ebx             #Exits with exit status 0
        int     $0x80                #Passes control to interrupt vector
```

As Michael has already said you need to call `sys_exit` to avoid segmentation fault .

*Edit* :
Here is good to mention that [`int 0x80`](http://www.linfo.org/int_0x80.html) invokes 32-bit system calls .
Using `int 0x80` for syscall on x64 systems is used for backward compatibility to allow 32-bit applications to run .

On 64-bit systems will be correct to use `syscall` instruction .
Here is a working version :

```
.section .data
StringToPrint: .asciz "Hello"

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

        movq    $1, %rax                # sys_write
        movq    $1, %rdi                # stdout
        movq    $StringToPrint, %rsi    # pointer to string to write
        movq    $5, %rdx                # string length
        syscall

        movq    $60, %rax               # sys_exit
        movq    $0, %rdi                # exit code
        syscall
```

Answer (score 2):

The calling conventions differ between 32 and 64 bit applications in Linux as well as other OSs. Additionally, for Linux the system call numbers are also different. This is how you invoke the `write` system call in Linux amd64:

```
; sys_write(stdout, message, length)

mov    rax, 1        ; sys_write
mov    rdi, 1        ; stdout
mov    rsi, message  ; message address
mov    rdx, length   ; message string length
syscall
```

Additionally, your application needs to call `sys_exit` to terminate, not return using `ret`. Read the calling conventions for your platform.

Comment: I'had just tried, but the fault keeps on coming out. I discovered that it happens when the ret statement is executed.

Comment: Your application needs to call `sys_exit`, not `ret`urn.